# Sort by certain column for the first 24 hours then order just by date

Tags: mysql, sorting

I am trying to sort a table by a certain column (say QUALITY column what is a float) for only the first 24 hours (i have a date-time column). Then it should sort the rest of the rows by the order of date because the quality column does not matter anymore. Only date-time matters after the 24 hours.

How can I accomplish this in mysql?

Comment: What do you mean by "*the first 24 hours*"?  First *from when*?

Comment: Rows in de table where the date-time columns are within the current day ( last 24 hours).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean 24 hours from now, you could use something like this -

select * from [tablename] t order by
case when date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) <  t.[date-time column] then t.quality 
else t.[date-time column] end desc

Comment: You probably ment "<" instead of ">" ,right? I tested it with a column of integers (different quality column) where 78 looks bigger then 724 :(

Comment: Can you post your table data and expected output?

Comment: Your answer worked for me if used "<" instead of ">". Only issue i have left is that with the sort mysql sees 7 bigger then 74. And 78 bigger then 724. Saw another post that one should use cast(quality_column as integer) but don't know how to integrate that with your query.

Comment: You are right about "<" vs. ">". So what is the datatype of the quality column? (I am assuming what you are saying is happening because it is not an int?)

Comment: The datatype is INT(8)